# fatal error encountered during command execution (mysql+c#)

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка в коде(ругается на cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()).
Предупреждаю сразу, что в C# я недавно(начал где - то 3-4 месяца назад), так что за неправильно сформулированные понятия прошу не пинать!

```
            try
        {
            string conStr = "server=XXXX;port=3306;Database=XXXX;uid=XXXX;password=XXXX;charset=utf8";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
            string sql = "set @max_msg_id = (select MAX(msg_id) from messages)+1; INSERT into messages(user, message, msg_id, date, time) values ('" + label4.Text.ToString() + "', '" + richTextBox2.Text + "', @max_msg_id, '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "')";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());`

Comment: Запустите `Workbench` и проверьте свой запрос (именно в том виде, который вы пихаете в `sql`). Запрос рабочий?

Comment: Приведите текст ругательства (ex.Message)

Comment: только fatal error encountered during command execution